# How do I install MariaDB to non-default root and data directories in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, mariadb

I'd like to install mariadb on Debian 10 with the `--basedir=/usr/local/mariadb` and `--datadir=/data/mariadb`. I've tried to add these options to the `apt install mariadb-server` command line but I get error messages saying the options aren't recognized.

So what then is the correct way to install mariadb using non-default root and data directories?

Answer (score 1):

Those are options for the mariadb program itself. You can put them in configuration files, overriding what is already set, e.g. on my system:

```
$ sudo ack datadir /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
21:datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
```

So I would suggest making your own custom config file in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` numbered after 50 and override it there:

```
[mysqld]
basedir = /usr/local/mariadb
datadir = /data/mariadb
```

Do bear in mind that the installation of the mariadb Debian package will create some databases in the default location first as part of its setup. You may want to pre-create your config files (which the install won't overwrite) so that it gets the correct settings at first startup and during the initial configuration.

Also mariadb doesn't currently have an AppArmor profile in Debian at the moment but it could grow one, so you'd have to watch out for that as it's very likely to restrict the daemon to only being able to access /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: This "pre-create your config files" tip here was key for me solving a similar problem.